# I can't see the simple database in the "Table" option in Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was following a tutorial on how to make a simple database in Visual Studio in this [site](https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-59-creating-a-database-in-visual-studio) here. The version of Visual Studio I use is the Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1

I was able to follow all the steps to make a database until I got stuck on one part. This part of the tutorial asks me to finally create the database by pressing "Update Database" option, then pressing the "Data Connections" option and finally, pressing the "Refresh" option (Data Connections>Refresh). But in the Visual Studio that I used, I could not see the option "Customers" in the "Table" option in the Visual Studio as shown in the picture below. It was supposedly show the "Customers" option after I've pressed Data Connections>Refresh.

[image]

How can I activate this "Customers" option in the Visual Studio?

I can't go further if I can't follow the tutorial....

Comment: try to click on that `tringular` button nears `Tables` inside `ACME.mdf`

Comment: try to add `New Query` => `Select * from Customers` and let me know

Comment: @ershoaib I tried to click the triangular button near the "Tables" option inside the ACME.mdf file. I can now see the "Customers" database I have been working on. Thanks! I have the answer now posted...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the simple database (in my case, named as "Customers") you have made after you pressed the "Update Database" option, then pressing the "Data Connections" option and finally, pressing the "Refresh" option (Data Connections>Refresh), you left-click the triangular icon near the "Table" option inside the "ACME.mdf" file. This triangle icon is shown by the red arrow on the picture below...

[image]

After you left-clicked the triangle icon near the "Table" option, you should now able to see the simple database you must be working on next time as shown in the picture below.

[image]

My problem really seems silly but I'm so new at using Visual Studio.

If you still don't see the "Customers" option after you did all the steps outlined above, post it on Stack Overflow....